# Kreait fcm error Firebase project [project-name] not configured

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying library fcm from https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase ,
this is my config file.

```
   'credentials' => [
            'file' => public_path('serviceaccount.json'), // config service account from firebase

            /*
             * If you want to prevent the auto discovery of credentials, set the
             * following parameter to false. If you disable it, you must
             * provide a credentials file.
             */
            'auto_discovery' => true,
        ],
```

and this is my result test on postman.

> Kreait\Firebase\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Firebase project [KANTIN-UNISBA] not configured. in file /path/to/application/vendor/kreait/laravel-firebase/src/FirebaseProjectManager.php on line 41 **

Comment: Hi, did you run the `php artisan config:clear` command?

Comment: Anyone solved this issue ? I am also facing the same.

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace `app` key under `projects` array with your project name in `config/firebase.php`.

Got it fixed just now so I think it might help someone else because it took me a while to debug.

[image]

Comment: And clear cache after doing this

php artisan config:cache